# How to access Python dictionary in Javascript Script in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, dictionary

I am working in Django, where I am sending a Python Dictionary into an HTML file.

In that HTML File, I want to access the Python dictionary and append the keys and values of dictionary into the Javascript arrays. I am able to access Python dictionary in HTML, but can't do the same in Javascript.

This is how I am able to access the values of Dictionary in HTML,

```
{% for key, image in predictedLabel.items %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ key }}</th>
        <td>{{ image }}</td>
      </tr>
  {%endfor%}
```

The Javascript script that I have is of Pie Chart, which is as given below,

```
      <script>
        var xArray = [];
        var yArray = []; 
        
        var xArray = ["Italy", "France", "Spain", "USA", "Argentina"];
        var yArray = [55, 49, 44, 24, 15];

        var layout = { title: "Distribution of Labels" };

        var data = [{ labels: xArray, values: yArray, hole: .5, type: "pie" }];

        Plotly.newPlot("myPlot", data, layout);
      </script>
```

I want to put the Python Dictionary Key into the xArray and the Values of Dictionary into the yArray. For that, I need to access the Python Dictionary in the Javascript script, but I do not know how to access the Python values in the Javascript script. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the dictionary in JSON form to the client. This is commonly done like this:

```py
import json

# ... send to client
json = json.dumps(dict_name)
```

Then in your template:

```html
<script type="application/json">{{ json }}</script>
```

Then in your JavaScript you can simply do:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('script[type="application/json"]'));
// do something with 'data'
```